# Goldwave : create a new 24bit wav - possible?

Tags: audio, wav

In Goldwave (v6.50, 2020), it is possible to open a PCM signed 24 bit wav file.

But it looks it is not possible to create a new (empty) wav file with PCM signed 24 bit wav file.

[image]

I can't find an option for PCM bit. How can I create 24 bit wav ?

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Why would you want an empty wav file?

Comment: I want to create a 24 bit wav file by combining/editing some (existing) 24 bit wav files.

Comment: It may be achieved by mainly working on one of the existing 24 bit wav files, but it is better (easier) to start with a new 24 bit wav file.

Comment: Then why not take the regular approach of laying them on separate tracks of a standard multitrack DAW & mixing them down as required? You can't start with an empty file & fill it with sand like a bucket & spade.

Comment: Any media editing software has the function create - new. So goldwave has it too but the option looks insufficient (or I am missing something)

Comment: None I've ever used, & I've been a sound engineer for 40 years. What's the point of creating a sound file with nothing in it, except to test digital silence. You make your 'new file' by saving a mix containing your existing sounds.

Comment: You are an expert.. so ironically you will never need some of the function in goldwave. For me, for example, if I want to focus on some part of an wav file, I need to create an empty file, and paste the part.

Comment: ermmm… no you don't. Audio editing really doesn't work like that. I've never used Goldwave, but I cannot imagine any audio editor considering that as a valid workflow method. It simply makes no sense to work that way. An audio file isn't a container to pour new data into, it's a fixed linear structure; to change it is to make a new version. Both can exist simultaneously, or one can overwrite the other, or non-destructively the app could maintain a changes xml, like  Adobe Audition does or in the project file likke Cubase/Nuendo or Logic.